# How do I verify clearInterval has been called with sinon?

Tags: javascript, sinon

So I have a React component that sets an interval like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.interval = window.setInterval(this.myFunction, 500);
}
```

And at the end of its execution, `myFunction` kills the interval by calling `clearInterval(this.interval);`

I'm using Sinon's awesome [Fake Timer API](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.5/fake-timers/) for making sure `myFunction` gets called after 500 ms like this:

```
let clock;

beforeEach(() => {
  clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
});

...

it('should call my function', () => {
  clock.tick(510);

  expect(myFunction).to.have.been.called;
});
```

But I also want to make sure the timer has been terminated. Is there a way to verify `clearInterval` has been called?

I tried it by using `expect(window.clearInterval).to.have.been.called;` but no luck there, I got an error message instead. Besides, the Sinon docs don't say anything about how to provide a stub to `clearInterval`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assuming you could test if `clearInterval()` was called, how would you know how long to wait before testing that? I.e., how would you know how many times the function ran before it decided to call `clearInterval()`?

Comment: @nnnnnn i wouldn't actually need to wait, as the interval was supposed to have been cleared at the end of `myFunction`. So, if `myFunction` had been called, I should be able to tell for sure the interval had been terminated.

Comment: If the interval is always cleared by `myFunction()` the first time it's called then it doesn't really make sense to use `setInterval()` at all: you should be using `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 1):

I got away with a different approach. Instead of verifying if the interval had been cleared, I changed my test to tick twice and make sure `myFunction` was only called once, like this:

```
it('should call my function', () => {
  clock.tick(510);

  // the interval should have been cleared the first time the clock ticked
  clock.tick(510);

  // given that the interval should have been cleared, 
  // myFunction shouldn't have been called more than once
  expect(myFunction).to.have.been.calledOnce;
});
```

Thanks a lot for the help, everyone! :)